# Can I define models in a loop in Keras?

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I am trying to train three different models with the same architecture on three different sets of data. This is what I have right now:

```
models_deaths = {}
models_deaths_histories = {}

epochs_per_severity = {"LARGE": 1000, "MEDIUM":100, "SMALL":5}

for severity in severity_map:
    inputs_deaths= Input(name='in_deaths'+severity,shape=(x_train[severity].shape[1], x_train[severity].shape[2])) 
    x_deaths = Dense(64)(inputs_deaths)

    inputs_aux_deaths = Input(name='in_aux_deaths'+severity, shape=[x_aux_train[severity].shape[1]])
    x_deaths = ConditionalRNN(128, name='LSTM_deaths'+severity, cell='LSTM')([x_deaths, inputs_aux_deaths])
    predictions_deaths = Dense(1, name='output_deaths'+severity, activation='relu')(x_deaths)

    models_deaths[severity] = Model(inputs=[inputs_deaths, inputs_aux_deaths], outputs=predictions_deaths)

    models_deaths[severity].compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mean_squared_error', metrics=['mse'])
    models_deaths_histories[severity] = models_deaths[severity].fit([x_train[severity], x_aux_train[severity]], 
                                                          y_train_deaths[severity], 
                                                          epochs=epochs_per_severity[severity], 
                                                          batch_size=256)
```

I'm changing the name of the layers, so I thought it would be fine, but I'm getting weird performance, and I'm wondering if it's because it's using the same layers in memory. Thoughts?

Comment: yes, you can. no problems with lopps.

Comment: When you say weird performance, does this mean the performance is better when you build the model individually? Have you verified the performance by building the models without the loop?

Comment: what is severity_map?

Comment: I tested building two models, one in the loop and one without. The models outside of the loop converged whereas the ones inside didn't. Maybe I just got unlucky with my data?